# Prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{g'\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}$ converges iff $\lim_{ n\to\infty}g(x)<\infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $g,g',\left(g'\right)^2-gg''$ are positive valued functions that exists on the domain $[1,\infty).$ Prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{g'\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}$ converges iff $\lim_{
n\to\infty}g(x)<\infty.$

**My attempt**
We know from the Hypothesis that $g(x)>0, g'(x)>0, (g')^2>gg'', \forall x\in [1, \infty).$

Suppose  $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{g'\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}$ converges  $\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{g'\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}=0$.
By $\epsilon$ definition of convergence of a sequence, I can say

For $\epsilon=1, \exists N(1)\in \mathbb N: \forall n\geq N(1) \implies |\frac{g'\left(n\right)}{g\left(n\right)}|<1.$

I am not able to proceed the proof. Can you please give hints?

My claim is $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x)<\infty.$ That is $\exists L\in \mathbb R,$ For a given$ \epsilon>0, \exists K(\epsilon)\in \mathbb R: \forall x> K(1) \implies |g(x)-L|<\epsilon.$

Comment: If $g(x)\le K$ for all $x$, then (since $g'/g$ is decreasing)$$\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{g'(n)}{g(n)}\le\int_1^N\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\,dx = [\log(g(x))]_1^N = \log(g(N))-\log(g(1)) = \log\frac{g(N)}{g(1)}\le\log\frac K{g(1)}.$$

Comment: That is, use the integral test on $g'(x)/g(x)$. You can show it's monotone decreasing by taking the derivative (with the quotient rule).

Comment: If the sum converges, then$$K\ge\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{g'(n)}{g(n)}\ge\int_1^N\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\,dx = [\log(g(x))]_1^N = \log(g(N))-\log(g(1)) = \log\frac{g(N)}{g(1)}.$$This proves that $g(N)$ is bounded.

Comment: @amsmath Agree so you are right and I was hasty

Comment: Integral test… right, i forgot this :(